# Why am I receiveing 'no module named wagtail' error when I try to launch django app

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I have an existing Django Project. I would like to use Wagtail with it. 
I have followed the instructions here:
http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.9/getting_started/integrating_into_django.html

However when I try to launch my app, I receive the following error message from uWSGI:-

```
    *** Operational MODE: preforking ***
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "./core/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
        application = get_wsgi_application()
      File "/opt/django/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
        django.setup()
      File "/opt/django/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
        apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
      File "/opt/django/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django
/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
        app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
      File "/opt/django/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 116, in create
        mod = import_module(mod_path)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
        __import__(name)
    ImportError: No module named wagtail
    unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
```

> ImportError: No module named wagtail

However I have installed wagtail.

I found this https://github.com/wagtail/wagtaildemo/issues/32

Which suggested

> Please can you run pip freeze and paste the output here?

I have run pip freeze, and this was the result: -

```
Django==1.9.12
Pillow==3.0.0
Unidecode==0.4.20
Willow==0.4
argparse==1.2.1
assert-exists==0.0.0
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.5.0.1
beautifulsoup4==4.5.3
caller-module==0.0.0
cp==0.0.0
distribute==0.7.3
django-appconf==1.0.1
django-autocomplete-light==3.2.1
django-compat==1.0.8
django-compressor==1.6
django-dual-authentication==1.0.0
django-hijack==2.0.1
django-htmlmin==0.8.0
django-ipware==1.1.2
django-mathfilters==0.3.0
django-modelcluster==3.0.1
django-taggit==0.22.0
django-treebeard==4.1.0
django-widget-tweaks==1.4.1
djangorestframework==3.6.2
evernote==1.25.1
html5lib==0.9999999
httplib2==0.9.2
not==1.7
oauth2==1.9.0.post1
olefile==0.44
pbr==1.8.1
public==0.0.0
publicsuffix==1.1.0
python-dateutil==2.2
pytz==2015.7
requests==2.13.0
setupfiles==0.0.0
simplejson==3.10.0
six==1.10.0
slackclient==1.0.5
stevedore==1.10.0
svn==0.3.36
uWSGI==2.0.11.2
url==0.1.5
virtualenv==13.1.2
virtualenv-clone==0.2.6
virtualenvwrapper==4.7.1
wagtail==1.9
webencodings==0.5
websocket-client==0.40.0
wheel==0.24.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

The next troubleshooting steps in link above, stated: -

> What do you get if you enter the following lines at the python command
>   line?
>
> import wagtail; wagtail import wagtail.wagtailadmin;
>   wagtail.wagtailadmin import wagtail.wagtailforms; wagtail.wagtailforms

Here is the result when I run those commands in python:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 13 2014, 11:03:55)
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import wagtail; wagtail
<module 'wagtail' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wagtail/__init__.pyc'>
>>> import wagtail.wagtailadmin; wagtail.wagtailadmin
<module 'wagtail.wagtailadmin' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wagtail/wagtailadmin/__init__.pyc'>
>>> import wagtail.wagtailforms; wagtail.wagtailforms
<module 'wagtail.wagtailforms' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wagtail/wagtailforms/__init__.pyc'>
>>>
```

Why am I receiving the 'no module named wagtail' error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have two python 2.7 installed, perhaps a built in one, and a manually installed one. The one that shows the import error uses the python located at:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/
```

While the one you had the module installed was located here:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/
```

You will need to either install wagtail to the first python or change the Django Project to use the second python.

Comment: Your pip is configured to install to the second python as well

Comment: Thanks that looks like a solid suggestion. I've just tried both approaches you suggested but can't fathom either. I used 'pip install wagtail' to install wagtail into my virtual env, but I'm not sure why Uwsgi is using this other python. Can you suggest how I can use pip to install wagtail in "/usr/lib/python2.7/"

Comment: First you will have to search in /usr/lib/python2.7/ and find the bin package of pip, then in terminal use `PathToPip/pip install wagtail` to specify to use that pip.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this: "find /usr/lib/python2.7 -name "pip" - which returned a single path... /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip  but inside the pip folder, there is no pip command

Comment: You are mentioning that you are using a virtual environment. Are you actually inside the virtualenv when you try to install wagtail and run the commands in your question post? It sounds very weird that you have 2 Python's in your virtualenv.

Comment: Thanks @abccd There's none in there, but i just searched the whole drive, and a couple were found, one is in /usr/bin -- do you think this might the one?

Comment: Thanks @MarcusLind I only have one python in the virtual env, but for some reason Uwsgi is using a python outside of the virtual env from what abccd spotted i think

Comment: quite possible, since `/usr/bin` can only be accessed by the system. And the first python is the system's python.

Comment: hmm.. i just tried /usr/bin/pip install wagtail -- but got a round of 'requirement already satisfied messages'

Comment: by any chance is there one located `/usr/local/bin`?

Comment: I will just check -- if i type this "/usr/lib/python2.7/python" would you expect it to launch python? because it doesn't

Comment: No there is no pip in /usr/local/bin

Comment: And did you *activate* your virtual env? Sorry, it's pretty hard trying to debug without actually being able to reproduce the problem...

Comment: One last thing you could try: before importing wagtail, type: `import pip; pip.main(['install','wagtail'])` which will install it to the python you're running with. If it shows `No Module Named pip` that means that there isn't a pip with that python..

Comment: Thanks, should I try the last syntax, at a python prompt, from within the virtual env?

Comment: just paste it inside your file, before where you imported wagtail, then run your app. Or you can do it in the django console.

Comment: Thanks I'm not running it with a file, i'm running this command - "uwsgi --chdir=/opt/django/src --module=core.wsgi:application --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=core.settings --master --pidfile=/tmp/dapp.pid --socket=/opt/django/core.sock --processes=5 --uid=www-data --gid=www-data --harakiri=20 --max-requests=5000 --vacuum --home=/opt/django/env --daemonize=/var/log/uwsgi/dapp.log" and that is generating those import lines, from the django file itself I think. --- I tried what you type 2 comments previous from the python prompt in the virtualenv but it said wagtail already installed

Comment: I've taken enough of your time here, thanks very much for your help, been a big help in the right direction, I think i'll try again tomorrow when i'm fresh as it's 5am here now. Hopefully I can get to the bottom of it. Really appreciate your time and help this morning, thanks again.

Comment: Ok, thanks, have a good night, sorry for not being able to solve your problem